# undefined symbol: g_task_set_name in glib

Tags: glib

I am upgrading Glib in my project. I am building it using meson. But I am getting below error: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name

Any Solution? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post what version of GLib do you have on your system?

Comment: currently GLib 2.58.3 and trying to upgrade to  GLib v2.66.8

Comment: `g_task_set_name()` was only added in GLib 2.60, so it could be that you're trying to compile with 2.58

Comment: In my docker environment I have 2.58. I am compiling 2.66.8 in docker.

Answer (score 0):

During building, meson should be using freshly-built new lib files of the current version, but somehow in your situation meson found the old 2.58 version lib files first, which lacked the g_task_set_name() symbol. Uninstall/remove/delete the current 2.58 glib lib should fix the problem.